# I'm trying to print sum and average of three numbers taken from user. Program's not running properly

Tags: assembly, mips, average

```
.data

prompt: .asciiz "Enter number 1: "
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter number 2: "
prompt3: .asciiz "Enter number 3: "
newline: .asciiz "\n"

fnum: .asciiz "Average is: "
snum: .asciiz "Sum is: "

 
.text
.globl main

main:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt  
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t1, $v0    
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt2   
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t2, $v0     

li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt3   
syscall

   
add $t4,$t1,$t2
add $t4,$t4,$t3

li $v0, 4
la $a0, snum   
syscall

move $a0, $t4     
li $v0, 1       
 syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, newline    
syscall

li $t5,3
div $t6, $t4,$t5


move $a0, $t6     
li $v0, 1        
syscall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't read the numbers from the console and store them in registers. Fixed your code and it should be working now. Added comments for you to understand.

```
.data


prompt: .asciiz "Enter number 1: "
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter number 2: "
prompt3: .asciiz "Enter number 3: "
newline: .asciiz "\n"

fnum: .asciiz "Average is: "
snum: .asciiz "Sum is: "

 
.text
.globl main

main:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt  #prompt for first number
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t1, $v0    #read number from console and store in $t1

li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt2   #prompt for first number
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t2, $v0     #read number from console and store in $t2

li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt3   #prompt for first number
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t3, $v0     #read number from console and store in $t2

add $t4,$t1,$t2
add $t4,$t4,$t3

li $v0, 4
la $a0, snum   #sum string printing
syscall

move $a0, $t4     
li $v0, 1        #print sum value
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, newline    #print newline string
syscall

li $t5,3
div $t6, $t4,$t5

li $v0, 4
la $a0, fnum   #print average string
syscall

move $a0, $t6     
li $v0, 1        #print average value
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall
```